# Using nao_leds to blink LEDs

Tags: ros, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cant seem to blink the leds on Nao using nao_leds.
Does anyone knows how do I do it?
I dont seem to really get the action goal stuff.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132921/using-nao_leds-to-blink-leds/) by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what I worked out, but something is still missing.

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials_naotalk')
import rospy
    
# Brings in the SimpleActionClient
import actionlib

import std_msgs.msg
import nao_msgs.msg
from nao_msgs.msg import *

  
def blink_client():
    rospy.init_node("blink_client")
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('blink', nao_msgs.msg.BlinkAction)
    client.wait_for_server()   
    #goal = actionlib_tutorials.msg.FibonacciGoal(colors.r=1, blink_rat_mean=1.5 ,blink_rate_sd=1.7 )
    #colors=[1,2,3,4], blink_rate_mean=1.5, blink_rate_sd=1.7
    goal=nao_msgs.msg.BlinkGoal(colors=(1,2,3,4), blink_rate_mean=1.5, blink_rate_sd=1.7)
    
    #BlinkGoal.colors=[1,1,1,1]
    #BlinkGoal.blink_rate_mean=1.5
    #BlinkGoal.blink_rate_sd=1.7
    
    
    client.send_goal(goal)
    client.wait_for_result()
    return client.get_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('blink_client')
        result = blink_client()
        print "Result:", ', '.join([str(n) for n in result.sequence])
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print "program interrupted before completion"
```

Below is the error message

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'r'
```

---

Originally posted by [dnth](https://answers.ros.org/users/11961/dnth/) with karma: 106 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0